# SHA512 with salt for iOS

Tags: php, ios, encryption, sha512

Hi is there anyone with a working SHA512 iOS implementation? The code doesn't seem to generate the same one I have on php.

```
<?php

$code =  hash("SHA512", '123' . '123' );
echo $code;
?>
```

**Output:**
263fec58861449aacc1c328a4aff64aff4c62df4a2d50b3f207fa89b6e242c9aa778e7a8baeffef85b6ca6d2e7dc16ff0a760d59c13c238f6bcdc32f8ce9cc62

```
- (NSString *) sha512:(NSString *) input withSalt: (NSString *) salt {


const char *cKey  = [salt cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
const char *data = [input cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
unsigned char digest[CC_SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH];
CCHmac(kCCHmacAlgSHA512, cKey, strlen(cKey), data, strlen(data), digest);

NSString *hash;

NSMutableString* output = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:CC_SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH * 2];

for(int i = 0; i < CC_SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++)
    [output appendFormat:@"%02x", digest[i]];
hash = output;
return hash;
```

}

```
[self sha512:@"123" withSalt:@"123"];
```

**Output:**
3cafe40f92be6ac77d2792b4b267c2da11e3f3087b93bb19c6c5133786984b44

Comment: @Zaph [he did](http://ca1.php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php).

Comment: from php.net: `string hash ( string $algo , string $data [, bool $raw_output = false ] )` so why is the third argument '123'?

Comment: @Zaph there is no third argument, just two concatenated strings `'123' . '123' == '123123'` it's written as if it were `$data . $salt`.

Comment: Is CCHmac the equivalent of php's hash_hmac() and not hash()? I'm grasping here but that's all I can see that looks out of place.

Comment: I think @IanStallings has it, [hashes and HMACs are not the same thing](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/29955/16242).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has two problems:

1. Your ObjC code appears to be calculating a SHA512 **HMAC** and your PHP code is calculating a SHA512 **hash** which are [2 different beasts](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/29955/16242). As far as I know [which is not far] the corresponding PHP code should be something like:

   ```
   hash_hmac('SHA512', '123',  '123' );
   ```
2. The output for the above is still much longer that the ObjC code, ie:

   ```
   0634fd04380bbaf5069c8c46a74c7d21df7414888d980c27a16d5e262cb8c9059139c212d0926000faf026e483904cefae2f5e9d9bd5f51fbc2ac4c4de518115
   ```

   Which is 128 characters [512 bits] long and ostensibly the *expected* length from SHA512 function.

Comment: This begs the question: Which does the OP want, HMAC (kCCHmacAlgSHA512) or SHA (CC_SHA512).

Comment: Thanks. This solved the problem. Fixed the php code and they now have the same output.

Answer (score 3):

You are using HMAC on iOS, you need to use SHA and concatenate "123" and "123" the same as you are doing for php. HMAC does *not* just concatenate the key and data.

Use:
`#import <CommonCrypto/CommonDigest.h>`
`extern unsigned char *CC_SHA512(const void *data, CC_LONG len, unsigned char *md)`

Comment: Here is the related apple doc: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/10.7/man3/CC_SHA512.3cc.html

Answer (score -1):

Edited the php code:

```
hash_hmac('SHA512', '123',  '123' );
```

This solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, but that solution was already posted one hour before this one.

Comment: OK, but that's a comment for the answer of Sammitch, it does not warrant a new answer. Don't forget to accept/vote up the answer of Sammitch.