# How to use WSSE in iOS with salted sha512 with more than 1 iteration

Tags: android, ios, symfony, sha512, wsse

I need some help with WSSE Header generations in iOS. The application it's written in Symfony2 which uses **sha512** algorithm with **5000 iterations** and **encode_as_base64** as true. For the mobile app, I found this question for encoding the password: [SHA512 with salt for iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18859005/sha512-with-salt-for-ios) although it's only one iteration. Using a simple loop which includes the last one would suffice it?

We found the code for the Android generation of the WSSE Headers: http://obtao.com/blog/2013/09/how-to-use-wsse-in-android-app/ It is possible to do the same thing in iOS or should we find another way for authentication, like OAuth2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to reproduce the same encryption as Symfony2 with the 5000 iterations, you can use the following code:

```
- (NSString *)hashPassword:(NSString *)password ansSalt:(NSString *)salt {

    NSString *passwordSalted = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@{%@}",password,salt];

    NSData *passwordData = [passwordSalted dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    uint8_t hash[CC_SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    CC_SHA512([passwordData bytes], [passwordData length], hash);

    NSMutableData *allData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    [allData appendBytes:hash length:CC_SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH];

    for (NSInteger i = 1; i < 5000; i++) {

        [allData appendBytes:[passwordData bytes] length:[passwordData length]];
        uint8_t hashLoop[CC_SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH];
        CC_SHA512([allData bytes], [allData length], hashLoop);
        [allData setLength:0];
        [allData appendBytes:hashLoop length:CC_SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH];

    }

    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithBytes:[allData bytes] length:[allData length]];

    return [imageData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];

}
```

Don't forgot to import CommonDigest.h:

```
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonDigest.h>
```

Answer (score 0):

For SHA512 try the following:

```
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonDigest.h>
    + (NSData *)sha512:(NSData *)data {
    unsigned char hash[CC_SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    if ( CC_SHA512([data bytes], [data length], hash) ) {
        NSData *sha512 = [NSData dataWithBytes:hash length:CC_SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH];        
        return sha512;
        }
        return nil;
    }
```

for WSSE headers check out https://github.com/laiso/CocoaWSSE

Comment: Thanks... I didn't know about CocoaWSSE. About sha512, this is only one iteration, right?

Comment: Yea from checking the website you provided it seems for the salt they simply append it at the end of the cleartext password padded with "{" and "}" so... user_password + "{" + salt + "}" this is what you will need to provide to the method and you will need to first convert it to an array of bytes.

Comment: `salted = clearPassword + "{" + salt + "}";
   for(int i = 1; i < 5000; i++) {
     byte c[] = new byte[sha.length + salted.getBytes().length];
     System.arraycopy(sha, 0, c, 0, sha.length);
     System.arraycopy(salted.getBytes(), 0, c, sha.length, salted.getBytes().length);
    sha = md.digest(c);
}` From the website, it iterates 5000 times.