# Equivalent of PHP funtion hash() with rawoutput for iOS

Tags: php, objective-c, hash, sha512

I'm trying to find the equivalent of this function for iOS :

```
hash('sha512', '123', true);
```

This is my method that i'm using which equates to: `hash('sha512', '123', false);`

```
- (NSString *)sha512{

    NSData *data = [self dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    uint8_t digest[CC_SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH];

    CC_SHA512(data.bytes, data.length, digest);

    NSMutableString *output = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:CC_SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH * 2];

    for (int i = 0; i < CC_SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++)
    {
        [output appendFormat:@"%02x", digest[i]];
    }

    return output;
}
```

how can i get it to give me the rawoutput ?

Comment: Define "raw output". Do you mean NSData instead of a string? An example would help. The code looks like a category on  `NSString`, is that what you want?

Comment: raw output is "raw binary data"
Yeah i'm using it as a category on NSString, for convenience

Comment: @JaredH Not really a duplicate, the OP does not want a `NSString` result and it is essentially what the OP provided in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want NSData output (which is a wrapper around the raw bytes:

// Category on `NSString` per OP request

```
- (NSData *)sha512 {
    NSData *dataIn = [self dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSMutableData *macOut = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:CC_SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH];

    CC_SHA512( dataIn.bytes,
              (CC_LONG)dataIn.length,
              macOut.mutableBytes);

    return macOut;
}
```

Test:

```
NSData *sha512Data = [@"123" sha512];
NSLog(@"sha512Data: %@", sha512Data);
```

Output (displayed in hex because that is how NSData displays it's bytes:

> sha512Data: <3c9909af ec25354d 551dae21 590bb26e 38d53f21 73b8d3dc 3eee4c04 7e7ab1c1 eb8b8510 3e3be7ba 613b31bb 5c9c3621 4dc9f14a 42fd7a2f db84856b ca5c44c2>

If a pointer to the bytes is needed just use `sha512Data.bytes`.

Answer (score 0):

This is more precisely what I was trying to accomplish, hope this can help for anyone who encounters the same problem.

[How to use WSSE in iOS with salted sha512 with more than 1 iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27983034/how-to-use-wsse-in-ios-with-salted-sha512-with-more-than-1-iteration)

```
- (NSString *)hashPassword:(NSString *)password ansSalt:(NSString *)salt {

    NSString *passwordSalted = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@{%@}",password,salt];

    NSData *passwordData = [passwordSalted dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    uint8_t hash[CC_SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    CC_SHA512([passwordData bytes], [passwordData length], hash);

    NSMutableData *allData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    [allData appendBytes:hash length:CC_SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH];

    for (NSInteger i = 1; i < 1000; i++) {

        [allData appendBytes:[passwordData bytes] length:[passwordData length]];
        uint8_t hashLoop[CC_SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH];
        CC_SHA512([allData bytes], [allData length], hashLoop);
        [allData setLength:0];
        [allData appendBytes:hashLoop length:CC_SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH];

    }

    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithBytes:[allData bytes] length:[allData length]];

    return [imageData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];

}
```